# What is the equivalent of “df -g” in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, solaris

I would like to convert "df -g" from solaris to linux. Would like to know what is the linux equivalent of "df -g"

On solaris man df will give option -g as such:

> Print the entire statvfs(2) structure.  This option is used only for
>   mounted file systems. It cannot be used with the -o  option.   This
>   option  will override the -b, -e, -k, -n, -P, and -t options.

I am currently unable to find -g for linux and would like to know if -g is now obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard (or widely adopted) option, and not present in any other *df* implementation except Solaris. (For example, OpenBSD's *df* uses `-g` for a completely different purpose.)

For Linux, you can get a text version of the statvfs() results using `stat -f` on each mountpoint individually.

```
$ stat -f / /boot
  File: "/"
    ID: 9a1f066700795d36 Namelen: 255     Type: zfs
Block size: 131072     Fundamental block size: 131072
Blocks: Total: 13928460   Free: 13756444   Available: 13756444
Inodes: Total: 3521952399 Free: 3521649824
  File: "/boot"
    ID: 38db9d923fe678d5 Namelen: 255     Type: ext2/ext3
Block size: 1024       Fundamental block size: 1024
Blocks: Total: 247591     Free: 128457     Available: 124361
Inodes: Total: 65024      Free: 64652

$ stat -f -c %n:%i,%s / /boot
/:9a1f066700795d36,131072
/boot:38db9d923fe678d5,1024
```

Comment: stat -f is a pretty good substitute but do you know of commands that can give all these in 1 command? Block size, Frag size, Total blocks, Free blocks, Available, Total files, Free files, Flag, Filename length

Comment: That's literally in the `stat -f` output already.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative in Linux systems, df can be used with the combination of "h" to be human readable and "P" to fix the alignment.

```
df -hP
```